# How to access mysql database using JSP scriplets?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying to access the database and retrieve a attribute 'sno' from it. I have hidden the value in a input field using the following code.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= request.getParameter("well_name") %>" name="well_name" id="well_name">
```

The above code is put in some other page when the user submits, it is passed to next page and here I am trying to access the database like

```
    <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/kn"
                       user="root" password="password"/>

    <p><%= request.getParameter("well_name") %></p>

    <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
        SELECT sno FROM well_name WHERE name = '<%= request.getParameter("well_name") %>' ;
    </sql:query>

    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <p><c:out value="${row.sno}"/></p>
    </c:forEach>
```

I am able to access the database when I provide a value which is defined like name = 'value'. I am not able to access like these please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try without single quote! `name = <%= request.getParameter("well_name") %>`

Comment: I tried it throws an exception.

Comment: Oracle docs suggests using sql:param, https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html.

Comment: did you check the value of : `request.getParameter("well_name")` is it same as the `value` you search for? check if there any extra characters such as space etc?

Comment: Yeah it is the same value.

Comment: try out the sql:param

Comment: it's encouraged that jsp is used to display data not for accessing database
try to with MVC architecture 
https://www.google.tn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjeuLG9_L3NAhUGWxoKHVi5Dc0QFggrMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fstruts_2%2Fbasic_mvc_architecture.htm&usg=AFQjCNEowwlhgJl5lccx_BcV3DgfWU_OwA&sig2=OxmHwB98GxDTShgVyhfCeQ&bvm=bv.125221236,d.d2s